# How to Upload website over internet by using IIS and domain

Tags: asp.net, iis, server

Please Explain me step by Step, how to host a website over internet. by using iis server with help of domain

Answer (score 1):

To host asp.net site in iis you could follow the below steps:

1)open the visual studio. Select your site and right-click on that-> Click publish.

[image]

2) in pick up publish target Select folder option and create choose destination where you want to publish the site. (make a new folder and publish a site in that folder) and then select publish.

[image]

3)open IIS manager(if not installed then installed it first).

4)expand the server name and right-click on sites and select add a new site.

[image]

5)enter the site name, physical path, and site binding details.

(Note: you need to have a public IP first, and bind the domain to the IP at where you purchased the domain name. after that, in IIS, bind IP and hostname as usual)

[image]

6) click ok.

if you have url rewrite rule and other external settings in your site you need to install that external module in iis.

for more detail please check the below link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-7-and-above-on-windows-server-2008-or-windows-server-2008-r2